# My partial view still calls/renders the _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have a MVC5 asp.net c# application.

I start off rendering the home page.

Now, when my user clicks a button it calls a jquery function.

The aim of this function is to get the html contents of a 2nd page and repalce the 1st page contents with that without refreshing the whole page.

So, in my _Layout page I have this DIV:

```
<div id="mainContent">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

This will load my default page.

The jquery function in this default page is:

```
$("#divHomeBanner").click(function () {
    var url = '/Welcome2';
    $('#mainContent').load(url);
});
```

the code behind is:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/Welcome2")]
public ActionResult Welcome2()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

I test by loading the default page
clicking a menu option
clicking the button that will 'take me back' to the welcome page (which for this example is called Welcome2 and is a complete copy of Welcome).

what I have noticed is that all the resources are loaded up again aka the JavaScript libraries.

I thought the whole intent of using partials was to render the content changes via ajax?

Is this wrong or have i implemented it wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view which you have made partial add this statement on top of it:

```
@{
 Layout = null;
}
```

This will make sure that your view `_Layout.cshtml` or if you have master layout with some other name does not gets called.

Another suggestion for you is to use `@Url.Action()` helper for generating urls instead of using magic strings:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Welcome2","ControllerName")';
```

Comment: thanks and thanks.  You make it look so easy and me so stupid!:)

Comment: yes, if this happens again, just make sure you have made Layout to null for your view.